# How do I sort table from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, dropdown

How do I create a simple sorting function for this. I know there is plugin like tablesorter. But it doesn't sort it from a dropdown list. Or is the plugin can be modified so that it can sort from a dropdown list. Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="UserID" name="UserID" readonly="readonly">
  <input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" id="UserOccupation" name="UserOccupation" placeholder="Occupation">
  <button type="button" name="button">Add</button><br>
</form>
Sort By:
<select>
  <option>ID</option>
  <option>Name</option>
  <option>Occupation</option>
</select>
<table id="table" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Occupation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Set id field to 1
  var id = $('#UserID');
  id.val("1");

  //Add 1 to the id in textbox
  function incID(){
    var str = id.val();
    var int = parseInt(str);
    var idVal = int + 1;
    id.val(idVal.toString());
  }
  //When button clicked
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    //create a new object
    var obj = new Object();
    //pass value dynamically from input box
    obj.id = $('#UserID').val();
    obj.name = $('#UserName').val();
    obj.occupation = $("#UserOccupation").val();
    //display data to the table
    var addrow = "<tr><td>" + obj.id + "</td><td>" + obj.name + "</td><td>"+ obj.occupation +"</td></tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(addrow);
    //Add 1 to id field
    incID();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the table is fairly easy to do yourself, all you'd have to do is sort the rows using javascript's sort method (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) and re-adding the rows to the table.

You could create sorting methods for different data-types like:

```
function sortByNumber(rows, selector, ascending) {
  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var numberA = parseInt($(selector, a).text(), 10);
    var numberB = parseInt($(selector, b).text(), 10);

    if (ascending)
      return numberA - numberB;
    else
      return numberB - numberA;
  });

  return rows;
}

function sortByText(rows, selector, ascending) {
  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = $(selector, a).text();
    var textB = $(selector, b).text();

    if (ascending)
      return textA.localeCompare(textB);
    else
      return textB.localeCompare(textA);
  });

  return rows;
}
```

(working example at https://jsfiddle.net/kg000ta7/)

However, if you plan to have a lot of rows or columns in your table, a plugin like tablesorter will probably perform better.

According to the documentation you are able to manually sort tablesorter by triggering the 'sorton' event: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var sorting;

  switch (field) {
    case 'ID':
      sorting = [[0,0]];
      break;
    case 'Name':
      sorting = [[1,0]];
      break;
    case 'Occupation':
      sorting = [[2,0]];
      break;
    default:
      console.error('Undefined sort field ' + field);
      break;
  }

  $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. The first solution without the tablesorter plugin work perfectly. But I have a question. What is the number 10 for in the function sortByNumber for? And why do you use the for loop?

Comment: Never mind my last question on the for loop. It is used for displaying the data to the table.

Comment: Correct, the loop is indeed for displaying the data in the table. The number 10 in parseInt is to make sure it parses the number in base-10 (normal human readable numbers from 0-10, 10-20, etc.) and not accidentally base-8. Which can happen if the text in the column starts with '0'.For more info about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Thank you so much for time sir