# Sort table based on dropdown option

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to sort my table based on the sorting option picked by the user from drop-down list. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529886/sort-a-table-by-drop-down-values-simplify-my-code) topic and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196521/how-do-i-sort-table-from-dropdown-list) one, but both of them are based on jQuery, but none of them seem to work for me, because I need pure Javascript solution.

My HTML:

```
<label>Sort order:</label>
<select>
  <option>Item asc</option>
  <option>Item desc</option>
  <option>Price asc</option>
  <option>Price desc</option>
  <option>Year asc</option>
  <option>Year desc</option>
</select>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>year</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Skoda Octavia</td>
    <td>7000</td>
    <td>2012</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Toyota Yaris</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>2011</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ford Focus</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>2009</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Since, I'm new, I'd be grateful for any help as of how to approach the problem.

Comment: please provide what you had tried so far in javascript

Comment: You should learn first how to build the table from static JSON data or any other format you prefer, then you should sort the table on the basis of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your problem can be divided into three smaller problems:

Get your HTML table data into javascript object, that encompasses array of objects, each having attribute that corresponds to column header and cell value, so that you can sort that array based on attribute values:

```
const jsonFromHtml = (tbody, thead) => {
    let tableJson = {rows:[]};
  [...tbody.children].forEach(tableRow => {
    let rowEntry = {};
    [...tableRow.children].forEach((cell, column) => rowEntry[thead.children[0].children[column].textContent] = cell.textContent);
    tableJson.rows.push(rowEntry);
  });
  return tableJson;
};
```

Sort row-items in arbitrary order:

```
const customSort = (arr, key, order) => {
    let sortCompare = order == 'Desc' ? -1 : 1;
  return arr.sort((first, second) => first[key]>second[key] ?  sortCompare : first[key]<second[key] ?  -sortCompare : 0);
};
```

Make up your table body inner HTML based on sorted array of rows:

```
const arrayToTable = (arr, tbody, thead) => {
    let rows = [];
    arr.forEach((row, rowNum) => {
    row = [...thead.children[0].children].map(th => row[th.textContent] ? row[th.textContent] : '');
    row = row.map(td => `<td>${td}</td>`);
    row = `<tr>${row.join('')}</tr>`;
    rows.push(row);
  });
  tbody.innerHTML = rows.join('');
};
```

```js
const myTableTbody = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody');
const myTableThead = document.querySelector('#myTable thead');

const jsonFromHtml = (tbody, thead) => {
 let tableJson = {rows:[]};
  [...tbody.children].forEach(tableRow => {
    let rowEntry = {};
    [...tableRow.children].forEach((cell, column) => rowEntry[thead.children[0].children[column].textContent] = cell.textContent);
    tableJson.rows.push(rowEntry);
  });
  return tableJson;
};

const customSort = (arr, key, order) => {
 let sortCompare = order == 'Desc' ? -1 : 1;
  return arr.sort((first, second) => first[key]>second[key] ?  sortCompare : first[key]<second[key] ?  -sortCompare : 0);
};

const arrayToTable = (arr, tbody, thead) => {
 let rows = [];
 arr.forEach((row, rowNum) => {
   row = [...thead.children[0].children].map(th => row[th.textContent] ? row[th.textContent] : '');
    row = row.map(td => `<td>${td}</td>`);
    row = `<tr>${row.join('')}</tr>`;
    rows.push(row);
  });
  tbody.innerHTML = rows.join('');
};

document.querySelector('#selectionOrder').addEventListener('change', function(){
 let sortKey = this.value.match(/[a-z]+/)[0];
  let sortOrder = this.value.match(/(A|De)sc/) ? this.value.match(/(A|De)sc/)[0] : 'Asc';
  let myTableJson = jsonFromHtml(myTableTbody, myTableThead);
  myTableJson.rows = customSort(myTableJson.rows, sortKey, sortOrder);
  arrayToTable(myTableJson.rows, myTableTbody, myTableThead);
});
```

```html
<label>Sort order:</label>
<select id="selectionOrder">
  <option value="itemAsc">Item asc</option>
  <option value="itemDesc">Item desc</option>
  <option value="priceAsc">Price asc</option>
  <option value="priceDesc">Price desc</option>
  <option value="yearAsc">Year asc</option>
  <option value="yearDesc">Year desc</option>
</select>
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>year</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Skoda Octavia</td>
    <td>7000</td>
    <td>2012</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Toyota Yaris</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>2011</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ford Focus</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>2009</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great! That's even more than I could expect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that defines the data in variables, and builds the HTML from that.

```js
// Define data in variables, not in HTML:
const columns = ["item", "price", "year"];
const data = [
    { "item": "Skoda Octavia", "price": 7000, "year": 2012 }, 
    { "item": "Toyota Yaris",  "price": 3000, "year": 2011 }, 
    { "item": "Ford Focus",    "price": 5000, "year": 2009 }, 
]

// Elements in the DOM
const orderSelect = document.getElementById("orderSelect");
const dataTable = document.getElementById("dataTable");

// Populate select list based on the columns of the data
for (const column of columns) {
    for (const dir of [" asc", " desc"]) {
        const opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = opt.text = column + dir;
        orderSelect.add(opt);
    }
}

function refreshTable() {
    const [sortBy, order] = orderSelect.value.split(" ");
    const sign = order === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
    data.sort((a, b) => a[sortBy] < b[sortBy] ? sign : a[sortBy] > b[sortBy] ? -sign : 0);
    // Clear table
    dataTable.innerHTML = ""; 
    // Create header row
    const row = dataTable.insertRow(-1);
    for (const column of columns) {
        const th = document.createElement("th");
        th.textContent = column;
        row.appendChild(th);
    }
    // Create data rows
    for (const record of data) {
        const row = dataTable.insertRow(-1);
        for (const column of columns) {
            const td = row.insertCell(-1);
            td.textContent = record[column];
        }
    }
}

// Populate data table
refreshTable();

// handler
orderSelect.addEventListener("change", refreshTable);
```

```html
<label for="orderSelect">Sort order:</label>
<select id="orderSelect"></select>
<table id="dataTable"></table>
```